# using classpath: in spring

Tags: spring, classpath

I have two questions regarding `classpath:` option in spring :-

1) Does `classpath:` search for resource relative to the document in which it is specified(in case of web applications)?

Suppose I use the following:

```
<bean class="mybean">
<property name="myresource" value="classpath:myfile.txt"/>
</bean>
```

in *myconfig.xml* under */WEB-INF/classes/config/myconfig.xml*. Then from where it will start its search?

2)Is it faster to search if I give direct location of the resource instead of giving `classpath:` i.e

```
<bean class="mybean">
<property name="myresource" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/myfolder/myfile.txt"/>
</bean>
```

instead of

```
<bean class="mybean">
<property name="myresource" value="classpath:myfile.txt"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 27):

> Does `classpath:` search for resource relative to the document in which it is specified(in case of web applications)?

No, `classpath:` is always relative to the classpath root.  If you put a `/` at the start of the path, it is silently removed.

> Is it more fast to search if i give direct location of resource instead e.g. `classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/myfolder/myfile.txt`

No, that won't work at all. The classpath root contains `/WEB-INF/classes`, so the path should be relative to that.

Don't confuse `classpath:` paths with file paths, they have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards

> This special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match the given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens via a ClassLoader.getResources(...) call), and then merged to form the final application context definition.

So `classpath:` starts at the root of your classpath.